# Calling Rest API from Javascript File: Data Return Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, rest

Hi i have created a javascript file where i make a call to rest api and get data. 
I want to return the data to the calling function from html page but the way the call works, i am not been able to.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" />
    <script src="jquery-G5API-1.0.0.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
           function JSFile() {
                var result = GetStatus(123456);
                alert('HTML: '+ result);
           }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="JSFile" onclick="JSFile()" />
</body>
</html>
```

query-G5API-1.0.0.js:

```
function GetStatus(token) {
     var url = 'some/url';

     var result = '';
     $.getJSON(url,function(data) 
     { 
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
     })
     .always(function(xhr, status) {
          alert( "finished: " + JSON.stringify(xhr));
          result = JSON.stringify(xhr);
      });

     alert('Returning result: ' + result);
     return result;
 }
```

The sequence in which alerts are being called:
    Returning result: empty_string
    HTML: empty_string
    Finished: json_data

Any suggestions on how to return json data from .js file to calling function in html file will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to resolve the promise to get your expected result. Check out the 
[jQuery deferred object api](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and observe the (simplified) following...

```
function GetG5Status3(token) {
    return $.getJSON('some/url')
}
```

---

```
function JSFile() {
    GetG5Status(123456).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5z17t9a9/) - simplified demo

Also, I am not seeing any usage of `token`

Comment: Perfectly what i was looking for, thanks. I will be using token in url but it did not add any value in my example over here, so i ignored it.